# AD620 or INA114 for EEG Device

Tags: amplifier, analog, integrated-circuit, signal, instrumentation-amplifier

I am trying to design an EEG device and found these suitable low cost instrumental amplifiers. I read their datasheets but could not find any significant differences. Which one is generally better? I will have 21 channels, use a battery to power the device, and read the data via a computer.

below are the datasheets:

INA114: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina114.pdf

AD620:  https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD620.pdf

Comment: "Better" in what way? I have no idea how an EEG works so, what are the important parameters for an InAmp in an EEG? Maybe cost is an issue that finds itself as an important component of "better"? "Better" does not really mean the same thing for two different people.

Comment: @Andyaka if you were to design the EEG, which component would you choose?

Comment: As I said above, I have no idea how an EEG works so, I don't know what parameters might be important when choosing a component.

Comment: Is this for medical use or are you just a hobbyist? A medical grade device is challenging, you need to do a massive amount of research, and will most likely need to build several prototypes before you get it right.

Comment: Your front end may be battery powered, but once you connect to a computer you have potential shock hazards. You will have low-resistance contact with human skin.

Comment: @Mattman944 I plan to use a laptop running on battery